# Accessing Vue methods from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just having a play with Vue.js (pretty new to javascript too) and trying to access the events in my Google calendar.

I keep getting 'undefined' when looking in the console.

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        client_id: 'my_client_id',
        scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"],
        events: {
            title: 'Upcoming Events',
            items: [],
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.loadCalendarApi();
    },
    methods: {
        addEvent: function (event) {
            this.events.items.push({
                title: event.summary,
                date: event.start.dateTime
            });
        },
        loadCalendarApi: function () {
            gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', this.listUpcomingEvents);
        },
        listUpcomingEvents: function () {
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                'showDeleted': false,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'maxResults': 10,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            });
            var events = this.requestEvents(request);
            console.log(events);
        },
        requestEvents: function (request) {
            return request.execute(function (resp) {
                resp.items;
            });
        },
    },
});
```

I think the offending code is somewhere in the requestEvents method.

I also know that 'this.addEvent' is not in scope to be able to refer to the Vue object from inside the request.execute function but I don't know what I need to change.

Can anyone help me or let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you could use the request => {} notation instead of function(request) {} notation, which will pass on the context to the executing method so this.AddEvent() will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways you could do it, one would be to change `execute(function)` to `execute(function, vue)` and pass `this` in as the second argument.  Then you could access it like so:

```
//update your execute function to pass along the vue variable into the response, then

requestEvents: function (request) {
        var events = request.execute(function (resp, vue) {
            for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                vue.addEvent(resp.items[i]);
            }
        }, this);
        return events;
    }
```

Or if you have jQuery available, you can take a look at `$.proxy()` which alters a function to use the current context: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

```
requestEvents: function (request) {
        var events = request.execute($.proxy(function (resp) {
            for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                this.addEvent(resp.items[i]);
            }
        }, this));
        return events;
    }
```

This way the anonymous response function will be run in the context of your Vue object.

Edit: I found this page as well which shows how you can bind the current context to a function using native JS, jQuery, or Underscore. Any of these would work: https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/5